# Dynamic scroll view for layout while text expandable in android

Tags: android

i am using expandable list view in my application. my application consists images, buttons and expandable listview. Here i want to add scroll view in dynamically while expandable list view text is visible otherwise no need to show scroll view in my layout.
Any one can help me how to do this thing.

Comment: you should post your tired code with appropriate information.

Comment: Try using expandable list view inside of a scroll view no need to add it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole layout under Scroll View but don't forget scroll view accept only one child so you can do like following:

```
<ScrollView>
---
...
<LinearLayout>
---
---
---
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

For example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/leatherbackground" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

----- Your xml code.....

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i want to add scroll view in dynamically when text expand in expandable listview only..

Comment: Ok. then use ListView. If your text expands, it will automatically provide scroll view. List view will fit in your demand perfectly

Comment: Rohit, i tried this way, here i set scroll view height fill parent..i want to change this scroll view height dynamically, how to set scroll view height dynamically?..

Comment: don't set your scroll view height "fill_parent", set it "wrap_content".